# How can I import RealtimeDragSelectingTool in go.js?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I use go.js as npm module, via Webpack. I would like to try RealtimeDragSelectingTool (https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/extensions/RealtimeDragSelectingTool.js) but the way of use in the provided documentation doesn't work. I import it like this:

```
import RealtimeDragSelectingTool from 'gojs/extensions/RealtimeDragSelectingTool'
```

If I use `go.GraphObject.make(RealtimeDragSelectingTool)`, it raises the following error:

> GraphObject.make requires a class function or GoJS class name or name of an object builder, not: [object Object]"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { RealtimeDragSelectingTool } from './gojs/extensionsTS/RealtimeDragSelectingTool';
```

The existing JS files in the `extensionsTS` directory are in UMD module format.

Comment: I added it but if I use npm run dev command, the following warning is raised: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Comment: Try a relative path.  Those samples in the `extensionsTS` directory also require those extension classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the problem is that RealtimeDragSelectingTool.ts starts with this: `import * as go from '../release/go'` which points to the main gojs directory. But I import it in a component where 'gojs/extensionsTS/RealtimeDragSelectingTool.ts' is an alias for `${project_directory}/node_modules/gojs/extensionsTS/RealtimeDragSelectingTool.ts` which means it will resolve '../release/go' as '${component}/../release/go' which is obviously not found.