# Typescript RealtimeDragSelectingTool import issues

Tags: typescript, gojs

I recently moved a project from JS to TS.

We used to use `RealtimeDragSelectingTool` as `schema.toolManager.dragSelectingTool` by importing `gojs/extensions/RealtimeDragSelectingTool`.

I saw that there is two import methods while working on typescript by using `extensionsJSM` or `extensionsTS`.

First I imported `extensionsTS` but got the same error as [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55138601), who in fact did not have a clear answer.

So I imported `extensionsJSM`, it is working but I have that error comming up in my IDE

```js
Type 'RealtimeDragSelectingTool' is not assignable to type 'DragSelectingTool'.
  Types of property 'box' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("c:/Dev/gojs-project/node_modules/gojs/release/go-module").Part | null' is not assignable to type 'go.Part | null'.
      Type 'import("c:/Dev/gojs-project/node_modules/gojs/release/go-module").Part' is not assignable to type 'go.Part'.
        The types returned by 'adornments.first()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'import("c:/Dev/gojs-project/node_modules/gojs/release/go-module").Adornment | null' is not assignable to type 'go.Adornment | null'.
            Type 'import("c:/Dev/gojs-project/node_modules/gojs/release/go-module").Adornment' is not assignable to type 'go.Adornment'.
              Types of property 'placeholder' are incompatible.
                Type 'import("c:/Dev/gojs-project/node_modules/gojs/release/go-module").Placeholder | null' is not assignable to type 'go.Placeholder | null'.
                  Type 'import("c:/Dev/gojs-project/node_modules/gojs/release/go-module").Placeholder' is not assignable to type 'go.Placeholder'.
                    Property 'computeBorder' is protected but type 'Placeholder' is not a class derived from 'Placeholder'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply copy the extension file to your project and import it, it works fine
RTFM...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).